# Do the sentences below mean the same?

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1. In any other family than mine, my right is being ignored.
> 2. In my family my rights are being ignored at a very high level, more than in all families.

If not how could I change number 1 to be like number 2 exactly.

Answer (score 2):

They do not mean the same thing. Currently #1 means, "In any other family *except* mine, my rights are being ignored." In other words, that *only* your own family pays attention to your rights. (Note that "rights" are plural, and therefore you use "are" with them, not "is.")

To make #1 work, you could say, "My family ignores my rights more than any other family I've heard of."

Comment: -Thank you, but what about a more literary style like : In not ( Or in no ) any other family than mine, my rights would be ignored.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not literary, because it's not grammatical as written ("In not/no any other" is not right), though it's getting closer. Flip it around: "My rights would be ignored in no other family besides mine" would work, but it's awkward. One fancy way might be "No family -- save mine -- would so ignore my rights." (Where "save" is used as "besides" or "except.") Remember that "literary" shouldn't mean "awkward," even if it is complicated sometimes.

Comment: I can't work out your meaning.  Do you mean "my family ignores my rights.  no other family would do that"?